# How do I set the working directory as the tab title in Terminal for Mac?

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

One of my Macs is running Mac OS Mojave and so for parity with my Catalina machine I switched the shell to zsh. Not sure exactly when but at some point I noticed the current working directory was never being displayed either in the prompt itself or in the title of the tab.

I found I way to restore the title to the prompt by adding this to my `~/.zprofile` file: `PROMPT='%~ '`. However, I have not been able to restore the directory name to the tab title:

[image: Terminal window with tabs]

This is quite frustrating when dealing with multiple tabs, as I do daily. It would seem to me that everything in the Terminal's settings is correct:

[image: Terminal Preferences]

Am I missing something or have I encountered a strange bug?

Comment: Open the Tab-tab in Terminal Prefs > Profile > [Profile name] (instead of the Window-tab) and check the radio buttons!

Comment: I haven't tested this, but try copying the /etc/zshrc and /etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal files from your Catalina system to the Mojave system (after backing up the original Mojave zshrc).

Comment: @klanomath Tried this, the same boxes are checked!!

Comment: @GordonDavisson I won't be able to try this until Friday but will give it a go

Comment: I should note, changing back to bash fixes it entirely. Something's up with zsh

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Copy the zsh setup files (`/etc/zshrc` and `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal`) from a Catalina system to the older system (preferably after backing up the original equivalent(s)).

I haven't tested this in Mojave, but I did in High Sierra, and it works fine there.

Explanation of the problem: Setting the Terminal window/tab title requires running some code (e.g. a shell function) to send the appropriate escape sequences, encoded version of the directory name, etc to the Terminal. In older versions of macOS, this was handled in bash by having `/etc/bashrc` run `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`, which defined a suitable function and set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to tell bash to run it each time it prompted for a new command. But since zsh wasn't the default shell, Apple didn't bother to create the equivalent setup scripts for zsh.

In Catalina, zsh *is* the default shell, so they wrote analogous setup steps and added them to `/etc/zshrc` and `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal`. The mechanics are different (for example, zsh uses `add-zsh-hook precmd` instead of the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable), but it does essentially the same thing. These files are not dependent on anything in Catalina; you can simply copy them to older systems, and they should work the same as they do in Catalina.